# Z-Transform of a Complex Number

Tags: z-transform

I have a more general question about $z$-transforms that I am having difficulty finding an answer to.

Suppose we have a two-sided sequence something along the lines of:

$$x(n)=a^{|n|}$$

where $a \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ is the set of complex numbers.

How does the $z$-transform process change when part of the original signal is a complex number?

This has not been addressed in any of the texts I have read or videos I have watched.  Or does this even have an effect on the process?

Comment: Nothing changes. The z-transform is defined on the set of complex-valued sequences to begin with. Not quite sure what kind of resources you have been looking at, then, because showing convergence in parts of the complex plane is a very prominent topic for people being introduced to the Laplace transform and from there the z-transform!

Comment: Thank you for the response!  The examples I have seen were based around non-complex signals, or generic cases, but never specifically addressed complex numbers or how it changed.  I did not think it would, but I could not find a definitive answer.